# How would I number my measures for my solo?

Tags: sheet-music, repeats, rests, anacrusis

How would I number the the top line, since the first measure is basically 1/2 of a measure, would I still put 1? The measure or 2 after the 2-4 are half measure, but two half measure make one so would I just put 5 for both combined or 5 and 6. I'm very confused here, I'd appreciate if anyone had an answer for this.

[image: Trombone solo with an anacrusis and a multi-measure rests and repeats.]

Comment: In this case, the repeat symbols are not bar lines. Pickup bars are not numbered. The first full bar is 1.

Comment: I am voting to reopen because I think it's clear that additional confusion is caused by the repeat symbol appearing in the middle of a bar, and that is not addressed by the proposed duplicate.

Comment: The rehearsal letters are your friend when the bar numbers need so much explanation. "We'll star two bars before (A) without doing the repeat" = OK. But "We'll start at bar 23" = Huh?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you note, the first “measure” isn’t a *whole* measure — this is called an anacrusis or a pickup, and it doesn’t count as the first measure.  If you have to give it a number it will be 0.

The next thing is that multi-measure rest, this counts as the first three measures 1, 2, and 3.

The fourth measure starts with a minim/half rests. But, the repeat sign doesn’t coincide with where a bar line would normally occur, so the first two notes of the solo are also in measure 4.

A similar thing happens an the end of the first repeated section.  The repeated sections ends with the first half of measure 12, and the second half comes afterwards.

Rehearsal mark A is at the start of measure 13.

[image: Image from question with measure numbers written in as described above "(0), 1–3, 4, (4), ...; 7, 8, 9, 10, ...; 12, (12), 13, 14, 15, ..."]

**NB**: The piece runs off the side of the image, so I had to guess about how many measures are off-screen.